# TENGO PROBLEMAS con ANDROID GET METHOD y POSTMAN

Tags: java, android, get, postman

En el trabajo me pidieron como mi primera app, para empezar

con un usuario y contraseña que use como `header` en mi código, mas su `url`, `params`, `cookies`.

me da este `json`:

```
    {
        "03_011A_DATAREQ": {
            "tableId": "F03B11",
            "rowset": [
                {
                    "NRO_INTERNO": "2",
                    "TIPO_INTERNO": "FA",
                    "FECHA_FACTURA": "06/03/2019",
                    "MONTO": 6050,
                    "FECHA_VENCIMIENTO": "11/07/2019",
                    "NRO_LEGAL": "001A0000100000007"
                },
                {
                    "NRO_INTERNO": "1",
                    "TIPO_INTERNO": "FA",
                    "FECHA_FACTURA": "06/21/2019",
                    "MONTO": 3509,
                    "FECHA_VENCIMIENTO": "21/07/2019",
                    "NRO_LEGAL": "001A0000100000006"
                }
        }
    }
```

Con su link :

> http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH?Cliente=80003

y params:

[image: params]

Cree un proyecto en `Android`:

```
main activity`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView textViewResult;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_result);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);




        Call<List<Post>> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getPosts("80003");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    textViewResult.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                List<Post> posts = response.body();
                for (Post post : posts) {
                    String content = "";
                    content += "03_011A_DATAREQ: " + post.get03011aDatareq() + "\n";

                    textViewResult.append(content);

                }


            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
                textViewResult.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }



}
```

interface

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

    @Headers({"Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept:application/json",
            "Cookie:JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743",
            "Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" })
    @GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH")

    Call<List<Post>> getPosts( @Query("Cliente") String cliente);
```

y sus clases donde se encuentran los datos del postman

```
    public class Post {

    @SerializedName("03_011A_DATAREQ")
    @Expose
    private com.example.getquantum._03011aDatareq _03011aDatareq;

    public com.example.getquantum._03011aDatareq get03011aDatareq() {
        return _03011aDatareq;
    }

    public void set03011aDatareq(com.example.getquantum._03011aDatareq _03011aDatareq) {
        this._03011aDatareq = _03011aDatareq;
    }




}

    public class _03011aDatareq {

    @SerializedName("tableId")
    @Expose
    private String tableId;
    @SerializedName("rowset")
    @Expose
    private List<Rowset> rowset = null;
    @SerializedName("records")
    @Expose
    private Integer records;
    @SerializedName("moreRecords")
    @Expose
    private Boolean moreRecords;

    public String getTableId() {
        return tableId;
    }

    public void setTableId(String tableId) {
        this.tableId = tableId;
    }

    public List<Rowset> getRowset() {
        return rowset;
    }

    public void setRowset(List<Rowset> rowset) {
        this.rowset = rowset;
    }

    public Integer getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(Integer records) {
        this.records = records;
    }

    public Boolean getMoreRecords() {
        return moreRecords;
    }

    public void setMoreRecords(Boolean moreRecords) {
        this.moreRecords = moreRecords;
    }



}

    public class Rowset {

    @SerializedName("NRO_INTERNO")
    @Expose
    private String nroInterno;
    @SerializedName("TIPO_INTERNO")
    @Expose
    private String tipoInterno;
    @SerializedName("FECHA_FACTURA")
    @Expose
    private String fechaFactura;
    @SerializedName("MONTO")
    @Expose
    private Integer monto;
    @SerializedName("FECHA_VENCIMIENTO")
    @Expose
    private String fechaVencimiento;
    @SerializedName("NRO_LEGAL")
    @Expose
    private String nroLegal;

    public String getNroInterno() {
        return nroInterno;
    }

    public void setNroInterno(String nroInterno) {
        this.nroInterno = nroInterno;
    }

    public String getTipoInterno() {
        return tipoInterno;
    }

    public void setTipoInterno(String tipoInterno) {
        this.tipoInterno = tipoInterno;
    }

    public String getFechaFactura() {
        return fechaFactura;
    }

    public void setFechaFactura(String fechaFactura) {
        this.fechaFactura = fechaFactura;
    }

    public Integer getMonto() {
        return monto;
    }

    public void setMonto(Integer monto) {
        this.monto = monto;
    }

    public String getFechaVencimiento() {
        return fechaVencimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaVencimiento(String fechaVencimiento) {
        this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
    }

    public String getNroLegal() {
        return nroLegal;
    }

    public void setNroLegal(String nroLegal) {
        this.nroLegal = nroLegal;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "03_011A_DATAREQ{" +
                "NRO_INTERNO" +  nroInterno + "\n" +
                "TIPO_INTERNO" + tipoInterno + "\n" +
                "FECHA_FACTURA" + fechaFactura + "\n" +
                "MONTO" + monto + "\n" +
                "FECHA_VENCIMIENTO" + fechaVencimiento + "\n" +
                "NRO_LEGAL" + nroLegal;



    }
```

me he basado en muchos vídeos de youtube, google y foros de acá, pero no me funciona. ¿Hay algo en que este fallando?

!muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Estas intentando acceder a través de http**s** desde la aplicación. Al parecer ese servidor no soporta https. Simplemente elimina la ***s*** de https

Analizando los paquetes de la red. el servidor no responde el handshake (apretón de manos), esto es necesario para establecer una conexión segura (**Client Hello**, **Server hello**).

Fíjate en el tiempo del paquete número 17 y el número 84. pasan 30 segundos aproximadamente y el cliente cierra la conexión por tiempo agotado (**timeout**) ya que el servidor no responde con un **Server hello**.

[image]

Comment: Muchas gracias! Se solucionó el problema quitando la S!